# Take snapshot of HighChart with render.text.css

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, screenshot, canvg

I have a simple highChart with x-axis label disabled. Later I am adding text in chart using the following code

```
function populateDateOnChart(chartID,minRange,maxRange) {
    var chart = graphChart;     
    if(chart) {
        var panelPlyGraph = Ext.getCmp(chartID);
        chart.renderer.text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', minRange), 1, panelPlyGraph.getHeight()-2)
        .css({
            color : '#666666' ,
            align : 'right',
            fontSize     : '18pt',
            fontWeight : 'normal'
        }).add();

        chart.renderer.text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', maxRange), panelPlyGraph.getWidth()-148, panelPlyGraph.getHeight()-2)
        .css({
            color : 'red',//'#666666' ,
            align : 'right',
            fontSize : '18pt',
            fontWeight : 'normal'
        }).add();

    }
}
```

I also, tried adding it to chart.events.load, as shown below but still not able to get it on the snapshot.

```
load: function() {
graphOffsets = {};
graphOffsets.left = graphChart.axes[0].left;
graphOffsets.length = graphChart.axes[0].len;
graphOffsets.min = graphChart.axes[0].min;
graphOffsets.max = graphChart.axes[0].max;
graphOffsets.invalidMax = inValidMaxdate;
populateDateOnChart('AccumulateGraph', graphOffsets.min, graphOffsets.max);
```

}

I am able to achieve the xAxis labels perfectly in my HTML page. The problem is, I need to save image of the graph. For this, I have used canvg. The image appears but this xAxis text which is set using chart.renderer.text.css is not appearing in the image.

The xAxis labels attribute is fine but it doesn't allow me to add padding before the first label and after the first label.

Can anyone please suggest me an alternative to canvg which will take chart.render.text.css also while saving image OR a way to position the labels in highChart as shown in code.

We do not have a div for the HighChart, we are putting it in ExtJS panel. Can this be a reason for the label not appearing in snapshot?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: highcharts already have options to export the chart as png image, pdf etc.

Comment: for external button to export  , check this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-exportchart/

Comment: I tried that, the xAxis labels are not coming in the generated image.

Comment: Move your renderer into [chart.events.load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load)

Comment: Well, in your load event I don't see a chart.renderer.text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', maxRange), panelPlyGraph.getWidth() - 148, panelPlyGraph.getHeight() - 2)
  .css({
    color: 'red', //'#666666' ,
    align: 'right',
    fontSize: '18pt',
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  }).add(); byt grapgChart refercenses. So im a little bit confused.

Comment: Hi Sebastian and Pawel, I have put the code in the question. I hope it's clear now, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know where is the problem - you are getting wrong container, as you suggested. Two things to be changed:

- `populateDateOnChart('AccumulateGraph', graphOffsets.min, graphOffsets.max);` - instead of `'AccumulateGraph'` use `this`: `populateDateOnChart(this, graphOffsets.min, graphOffsets.max);` - now you will pass on chart object, not just the ID
- update your method accordingly:

  ```
      function populateDateOnChart(chart,minRange,maxRange) {
              chart.renderer.text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', minRange), 1, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - 20)
              .css({
                  color : '#666666' ,
                  align : 'right',
                  fontSize     : '18pt',
                  fontWeight : 'normal'
              }).add();

              chart.renderer.text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', maxRange), chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth -148, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - 20)
              .css({
                  color : 'red',//'#666666' ,
                  align : 'right',
                  fontSize : '18pt',
                  fontWeight : 'normal'
              }).add();
      }
  ```

I'm just curious - why can't you use axis labels? For example you can use `xAxis.tickPositioner` to return only first and last values like this:

```
xAxis: {
  tickPositioner: functin(min, max) {
    return [min, max];
  },
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to position the labels independently using xAxis, this is why I added it as separate text through chart renderer.